# add 0x to a byte

Tags: programming

I have a **byte** variable CardNumberByte with a value of E8 if i print out as HEX:

```
Serial.println(CardNumberByte, HEX)
```

which returns E8.

What I would like to do is to "append 0x as prefix" so that it is equivalent to

```
Char CardNumberByte=0xE8;
```

how should i concatenate 0x to CardNumberByte?

[here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39861/how-to-convert-an-hex-string-to-an-array-of-bytes) is the reason i need to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just printing it first?

Comment: no, i need a char variable with the value of 0x28, not just 28 printed out using HEX format in the example. 0x28 will be an address for the sensor

Comment: That's a *completely* different question from what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what you actually need help with.

Comment: "How do I convert a string with two hexadecimal digits to a byte?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because very elemental programming question unrelated to Arduino

Comment: I think there is a serious basic misunderstanding of very elementary C (and even basic programming and even "what a computer is") concepts here. You need to go right back to basics and learn how to count (metaphorically) before you start tacking calculus.

Comment: The whole idea of "add a prefix to a byte variable and store it in the byte variable" is completely meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at you question and the question you linked two and I've tried to join the dots to give you an answer, so I might be well off the mark, but...

I think you might have misunderstood what `0x28` means.

0x?? means that the ?? represent a hexadecimal number rather than a decimal number.

So 10 (Ten) in decimal is the same as 0x0A in hex or B00001010 or in binary or even 012 in octal.  (See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/IntegerConstants for more details)

So you want to have some code that says:

```
char Address = 0x28;
```

This is assigning the hexadecimal value 28 to the variable `Address`.  You could also write:

```
char Address = 40;
```

In this case you are assigning the value decimal 40 (which is hex 28) to the variable.  If you want to write strange code that is misleading you could write:

```
char Address = '(';  // ( is ASCII character 0x28 or 40 - Don't do it like this!
```

One other important thing here is that the `char` type in this case is not being used as type that holds a printable character, its being used as a signed 8 bit number.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question you asked is:

```
Serial.print("0x");
Serial.println(CardNumberByte, HEX);
```

But what you want to do according to the comment you posted is *parse* `"E8"` to give you `0xE8`.

```
int parseHex(char* input){
    int result = 0;
    while(input && *input){
        if(*input >= '0' && *input <= '9'){
            result <<= 4;
            result+= *input - '0';
        }
        if(*input >= 'a' && *input <= 'f'){
            result <<= 4;
            result+= *input - 'a'+10;
        }
        if(*input >= 'A' && *input <= 'F'){
            result <<= 4;
            result+= *input - 'A'+10;
        } 
        input++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to advance `input` and check if it's `\0` before shifting.

Comment: Why are you using: `input <<= 4;` on pointer?

Comment: @KIIV because I was far too hasty...

Comment: I think you should use: `result = result<<4 + ...` or at least move that bitshift before the `result += ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
  char buffer[20];
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "0x%X", 1234);
  Serial.println(buffer);
```

You have to study the classic C print functions.