# Convert comma-delimited Arduino String of hex values to array of bytes

Tags: arduino-nano, string

My apologies if this is a naive question. How do I convert a `String` which has hex values to a byte array that has those hex values?

This:

```arduino
String s = "0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff";
```

Needs to be converted to this:

```arduino
char test[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
```

I used the following procedure. It does convert it, however, each character is saved as a character as opposed to hex value:

```arduino
unsigned int str_len = s.length() + 1;
char charArray[str_len];
s.toCharArray(charArray, str_len);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: there is no such thing as a hex byte ... it is simply an 8 bit number ... you could use 0xff or 255 because they are the same value

Comment: @jsotola This is just an example, I need this to be used for all hex values. How do I convert the string to byte array?

Comment: Related: [How to convert a hex string to an array of bytes?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39861/how-to-convert-an-hex-string-to-an-array-of-bytes)

Answer (score 3):

You only convert the String object to a char array. It need to further split the char array into substring, and then convert it to number.

To split the char array, you can use [strtok()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function in c++ to do the job.

There is no str conversion function that can convert `"0xff"` into `uint8_t` directly. However, as @rubemnobre mentioned [strtol()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) can be used to convert a c string to a `long` (in Arduino, it is 4-byte number) and further cast into a `uint8_t` and store in a byte array.

```arduino
String s = "0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff";

// Convert String object to char array
unsigned int str_len = s.length()+1;
char charArray[str_len];
s.toCharArray(charArray, str_len);

uint8_t byteArray[7];
int i=0;

// split charArray at each ',' and convert to uint8_t
char *p = strtok(charArray, ",");
while(p != NULL) {
  byteArray[i++] = strtoul(p, NULL, 16);
  p = strtok(NULL, ",");
}

// Print the byteArray
for (i=0; i<sizeof(byteArray)/sizeof(char); i++) {
  Serial.print(byteArray[i]);
  Serial.println(", ");
}
Serial.println();
```

Comment: If you're not strtol's using "endptr" (&ptr in your case) you can just replace it with `NULL` and the parameter will be ignored. Also if you're casting to uint8_t then strtoul would be a better choice.

Comment: @Majenko, thanks and upvoted for your comment, make the code cleaner and simpler. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are C functions that can convert text to number. For example, [`strtol()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm) or `atoi()`. Here is a little snippet to get you started:

```arduino
char *str = "FF";
char *ptr;
int result = strtol(str, &ptr, 16); //the 16 is the base the string is in (HEX -> base 16)
```

`result` will have `0xFF` or `255` by the end. You can use this to achieve what you are trying to do. Take a look at [this](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) for functions you can use to manage your `String`.